# Pass time variable from Javascript to Apex

Tags: apex, javascript, time

Im trying to send time variable from LWC javascript To apex but not able to do that because of the format.
what is the correct format in which I can send the time variable.
Tried sending in the following format

```
hh:mm:ss
12:23:05
T12:23:05Z
12:23:05.000Z
T12:23:05.000Z
```

.js

```
this.currenttime = "12:23:05";
submitB({ starttime : this.currenttime)}
```

apex

```
public static void newTimeCharge(Time starttime)
```

what is the proper format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set current time as time only instead of string

```
 currenttime = new Date().getTime();
 submitB({ starttime : this.currenttime})
```

Second Option:
You can change parameter type from Time to String in the apex class and parse it their in apex using newInstance method of Time class by splitting the string using ':' and pass it as integer value in the function

```
Time.newInstance(Integer hour, Integer minutes, Integer seconds, Integer milliseconds).
```

Comment: Please reverse the order of your solutions since the second is the one that solves the asked question.

Comment: Also in the Date-based solution, please remove the "today" variable - you didn't show it consistently, it is "now" not "today" and you can easily inline it. Finally, it would be far better to show Date-based handling of a hard-coded date since the OP shows that themselves.

Comment: Thanks Phil, updated  as per your comments. I have not used hardcoded string because the variable name is currentTime so it should be the dynamic current time and not the hardcoded one. I assumed that in the question hardcoded value is just for example/reference purpose to know about the actual format.